# Half screen coming blank for my google map

Tags: android, maps

Google map screen is opening with blank bottom sheet when i open from my app.

Here is the approach i used it is working for samsung j2 but not for nexus,oneplus and many kore 5.Tried similar question but was not able to find any.

I only have lat long with me

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

this is how it looks with blank bottom sheet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Uri geoLocation=Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("q",location).build();
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(geoLocation);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
            startActivity(intent);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: i only hav lat , long not location object

Comment: create location object like this 
android.location.Location loc1 = new android.location.Location("");
        loc1.setLatitude(latitude);
        loc1.setLongitude(longitude);

Comment: No issue is not this i tried all ways in documentation